# CSS Layout - Avoid vertical scroll bar

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a HTML CSS Layout using div tag.

[Code here](http://jsbin.com/ujemaq/4)

Now it display a vertical bar. I want to avoid this vertical bar, and would like to display only if the content is big.

Answer (score 2):

May you wnt an [Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)  than put your `footer` outside the `#container`.

Check this http://jsbin.com/ujemaq/17

Comment: Didn't notice my left-nav div css and content div css are modified. Actually i need their height to reach the bottom of the page ending above the footer div. Any idea how my original problem can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Ok your actual problem arises with the height ambiguity, see these line:

```
#container{
    min-height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;       /* this causes container to a 100% height of body*/
}
#header{
    width:100%;
    height:55px;     /* this takes 55px of container height*/
    /*border:2px solid;*/
}
#menu{
    width:100%;
    height:20px;   /* this takes another 20px of container height*/
    /*border:2px solid;*/
}
#left-nav{
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    /*border:2px solid;*/
}
#content{
    height:100%;  /*You thinking of getting full height of container but the 75px height is already grabbed by header and menu, so while expanding content to 100% height a vertical scrollbar appears */
    /*border:2px solid;*/

}
```

Comment: if you follow OP's link and scroll down, you'll see there's an orange bar that's meant to display.

Comment: @Asif but my footer is not getting displayed.

Comment: My apologies, i got the yellow footer of jsbin and thought of it as your own footer. pardon.

Answer (score 0):

apply this css

```
body,html{
  height:100%;
}
    #container{
        min-height: 100%;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    #header{
        width:100%;
        height:55px;
        /*border:2px solid;*/
    }
    #menu{
        width:100%;
        height:20px;
        /*border:2px solid;*/
    }
    #left-nav{
        width:20%;

        float:left;
        /*border:2px solid;*/
    }
    #content{
        height:85%;
        /*border:2px solid;*/

    }
    #footer{
        background-color:#FFA500;text-align:center;
    }
    </style>
```